# Custom domain name with Heroku

Tags: heroku, subdomain

I've registered a custom domain name but am getting confused with how to point it to my app on Heroku. If I understand correctly, I need to update my CNAME Records where I registered my domain name.

I've pointed my CNAME to my app on heroku. However it appears I also need to update the A-Record and enter the IP address of my Heroku app... This is where I'm stuck, as Heroku does not seem to provide any IP Addresses.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point any host name at heroku, like `www.yourdomain.com` by adding a `CNAME` record:

```
CNAME www.yourdomain.com your-heroku-app.herokuapp.com
```

This will forward any DNS queries for `www.yourdomain.com` to resolve to the IP for `your-heroku-app.herokuapp.com`.